# Multiple linear regression in MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

Which is the easier way to perform multiple linear regression in MATLAB given that my dataset consists of 384 explanatory variables and 1 dependent variable? In fact, I need to compute coefficients, corresponding residuals, as well as the generalization error when testing this linear model using, 30 say, examples not in the training set.

I think that [this function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/data_analysis/f1-5937.html) works fine for me, but I am not sure how to make it work with a big number of explanatory variables.

I know that there should be a more efficient way to construct such a model, but this is just a preliminary task of my research.

All ideas are welcome.

EDIT:
I think I found it. Could you please confirm that the following is correct?

```
X = DATA(1:101,1:99);
[M,N] = size(X);
y = DATA(1:101,100);
X = [ones(M,1) X];
b = regress(y,X);
```

BUT, what about the residuals and the generalization error?

Comment: A good way to check things like this is to simulate the data using known coefficients and very small random error terms, and then check that the output is consistent with the simulation.

Comment: Broken link: please update the link to "this function".

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [mvregress](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/mvregress.html) command?

```
load flu

% response: regional queries
y = double(flu(:,2:end-1));  

% predictor: national CDC estimates
x = flu.WtdILI;             
[nobs,nregions] = size(y);

% Create and fit model with separate intercepts but 
% common slope
X = cell(nobs,1);
for j=1:nobs
    X{j} = [eye(nregions), repmat(x(j),nregions,1)];
end
[beta,sig,resid,vars,loglik] = mvregress(X,y);
```

Comment: Both regress and mvregress work for copefficients and residuals, but what about the generalization error? how to compute that?

Comment: how about sum(resid) or sum(resid.*resid) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares

Comment: I am a bit confused. As generalization error, the paper gives a series data with length the same as the number of testing points. Any ideas??

Comment: lets say you have 100 data points you use 70 of them for the modeling and 30 for validation. you use those 70  for calculation of model generalization error via model residuals.

Comment: I still don't understand. Let's say that I use these 70 data points to compute the coefficients. Then, I have to use these coefficients in addition to the 30 data points so that to provide a number of respond values that approximate the real respond variables, right? But how exactly yo produce the generalization error from all these data? could you provide sample code in matlab?

Comment: You just use 70 of them and the 70 response values to calculate model error. The other 30 and the response of 30 is just for model validation errors. they are two different errors.

Comment: ...and the generalization error refers to which of these two??? would it be easy to provide some Matlab code for that?

Comment: the difference between 70 observations and 70 responses is the residuals. the squared sum of the residuals are the general model error. the matlab code is just sum(resid.*resid). but note that sum squared error is just one of the ways to calculate general model error.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simulate your model on the validation set? As I understand that is exactly generalization error.

```
X = DATA(1:101,1:99);
[M,N] = size(X);
y = DATA(1:101,100);
%X = [ones(M,1) X]; - this thing is done automatically
r = randperm(size(X, 1));
trainX = X(r(1:70,:), :);
trainY = y(r(1:70,;), :);
testX = X(r(71:end,:),:);
testY = y(r(71:end,:),:);
model = LinearModel.fit(trainX, trainY);

generalizationError = mse(model.predict(testX) - testY)
```

Also `model` variable provides lots of info about the regression.

Comment: this procedure should be repeated a sufficient number of times to estimate generalization performance (the value will likely differ for each split of the data set).