# How to compute the generalization error (test error) in a multivariate regression?

Tags: regression, matlab, error, multivariate-regression

How can I, after running multivariate linear regression, compute the Generalization Error (also known as Test Error)? Are there many practises to do that?

EDIT: Can the following be considered as Generalization (or Test) Error?

```
y = data1; [M,N] = size(y);
X = [ones(M,N) data2];
y_train = y(M-30-483:M-30,:);
X_train = X(M-30-483:M-30,:);
y_test = y(M-29:M,:);
X_test = X(M-29:M,:);

[b,~,r,~,stats] = regress(y_train,X_train);
[M,N] = size(data2);
figure; plot(r);
axis([0,N+1,-Inf,Inf]);

y_estimated = X_test * b; y_expected = y_test;
generalization_error = y_expected - y_estimated;
figure; plot(generalization_error);
```

Comment: I take it that you're wondering how to do this in Matlab?

Comment: @MånsT: Basically yes, but I would also appreciate if you could provide a few hints regarding the theoretical aspects of this concept...

Comment: possible duplicate you can check this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32748/multiple-linear-regression-in-matlab/32760#32760

Answer (score 2):

What you are showing above is indeed an estimate of the model performance on unseen data (generalization error). However the variance of your test data set will presumably be non-negligible and so a better way to estimate the generalization error would be through cross-validation.

Try the `crossval` function in Matlab or use `cvpartition` to define and your cross-validation folds and iterate though using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Generalzation error is usually further summarized to obtain one number for all samples:

From your differences, you can e.g. calculate

- root mean squared error `sqrt (mean ((yhat - y)^2))`
- mean absolute error `mean (abs (yhat - y))`